# How can I disable the left and right arrow keys of Photoswipe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrow-keys, photoswipe

how to disable left and right arrow keys of Photoswipe ?

I tried the following

- keyboard: false,

and this code block

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

```
    if (["ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight"].includes(e.code) &&
        (e.target === pswpBtnLeft || e.target === pswpBtnRight)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Disable left and right arrow keys
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (["ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight"].includes(e.code)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Assuming that the photoswipe is active currently on the web page.